# What is the best way to decorate fragments of text in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I need to insert custom views into Text in SwiftUI. In other words to decorate some fragments of text, like formula field in Numbers app.
I still novice in swiftUI and Xcode, so just can't figure out how to begin and google it. ‍♂️

[image]

I would be grateful for any help in pointing out areas for further deepening. I suppose, it's about UIKit…

**UPDATE**
What kind of UI element I have to use to achieve result like on picture: textfield, which may contain another intractable UI elements?
I want some words become buttons, other have image on background.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a full answer here as it seems that you're the kind of developer who'd like to figure this out for yourself. (Please, correct me if I am mistaken in assuming this.)

The gist is that the `SwiftUI` way of doing it is probably still not nearly as simple to do as the `UIKit` way.

In `UIKit`, you're likely looking at creating a wrapper view *or subclass of* a `UITextView` which will manage its subviews, handle touch and text input events, and update the cursor of the `UITextView`.

[LinkedIn's Hakawai](https://engineering.linkedin.com/ios/introducing-hakawai-powerful-mentions-enabled-text-view-ios) sounds like something you could consider using to power this...

You can then expose this to `SwiftUI` via the `UIViewRepresentable` wrapper type.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like what I'm looking for. Time is much more valuable to me, I do not want to spend it too much on what has already been done by others, I better understand how it works in the process.  
I prefer the path from simple to complex, at this stage of my training I would not want to deeply understand someone else's project.

Comment: @cyber-bot Great! If you feel that I've sufficiently answered your question, please upvote and/or accept the answer by clicking on the hollow checkmark the left of the answer. Otherwise, this will linger in the graveyard of "Unanswered" questions. Thanks.

Comment: Already upvoted, but your answer is not what I expected to get, because I still on the same point as yesterday. UITextView was the next one that I was going to study on my own. I would like to get more specific instructions on how to achieve the same result as in the Numbers application.

Comment: @cyber-bot Fair enough, but I think you'll need to clarify your question more in order to get the answers you are looking for. i.e. what do you mean by the "same result as in the Numbers application."?

Comment: @cyber-bot With all due respect, I believe that my answer gives you a lot to work with: You use a `UITextView` with a dynamic cursor and custom accessory views. LinkedIn's library will go a long way with that...

Comment: Give me time to figure it out :)